# Converting .odb file to .db with OpenOffice Base or LibreOffice Base

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I have a .odb file that I'm trying to convert to a .db file for compatibility with my preferred program. After some rudimentary Googling I tried the instructions in [this thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=14408) and came up with this error:

```
1: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.
```

The thread I found was from 2009 so it seems as though the latest versions of OpenOffice Base and LibreOffice Base no longer support the `SCRIPT` statement. The other links I have found through Google ask me to do roughly the same thing as in the linked thread. What I am trying to do here is relatively simple. All I need is for my open database (.odb) file to be used as an SQL database (.db) file.

Comment: What engine does your .odb file use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SCRIPT` statement is for the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) engine, which is the engine used by default when creating a new LibreOffice Base file.  From the error message, it looks like the engine is MS Access (JET database engine) instead.

If that is the case, then instead of LibreOffice Base, maybe you need a different conversion tool:  https://serverfault.com/questions/470259/how-can-i-convert-an-ms-access-database-mdb-file-to-a-sqlite-database-db-f.